# Link login activity to the main activity that can pass the user id

Tags: android, string, authentication, android-asynctask, equals

how to pass the user id to the next activity using android studio?
currently in my app if user enter invalid password in login activity its still go the same activity as valid password.. how i want to solve it.

this is my code for login.php

```
<?php  
    require "init.php";  
    $user_name = $_POST["login_name"];  
    $user_pass =  $_POST["login_pass"];  
    $sql_query = "select name from user_info where user_name like '$user_name' and user_pass like '$user_pass';";  
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
    {  
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $name =$row["name"];  
        echo "success";  
     } else  {  
         echo "fail";  
     } 
 ?>
```

code background.java (asynctask)

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result)
{
        if (alertDialog.setMessage(result)=="success")
        {
        alertDialog.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Index.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle int = new Bundle();
        int.putInt("id", 1); 
        intent.putExtras(int);
        ctx.startActivity(intent); }

}
```

i also run using equal function but does not work

```
       if(result.equals("success"))
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Index.class);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           ctx.startActivity(intent);
       }
    else
       {
           alertDialog.setMessage(result);
           alertDialog.show();
       }
```

this is my first time developing mobile apps and using android studio.
sorry for asking silly question, tq

Answer (score 1):

For pass the user id to another Activity. Just use the simple code

Current Activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ReceiverActiviity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("userId",your_user_id_Value);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

ReceiverActiviity:

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("userId", -1); // -1 is the default value
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

**if (alertDialog.setMessage(result)=="success")**
this line has problem, I guess the variable alertDialog is an instance of AlertDialog.Builder, and setMessage(string) method it returns itself not a string, so that if sentence will not be true forever.
by the way, compare a string in Java usually use equals method.

Comment: you are using a setter and asking if it equals "success" I doubt it gives you true. There is so much wrong in that condition lol.